# Uploading a file on IE11 + Safari using Selenium (via BrowserStack)

Tags: selenium, file-upload, integration-testing, internet-explorer-11, browserstack

While trying to run automated tests on BrowserStack to test a webpage on IE11 and Safari, I'm unable to upload a document from the test-running assembly.

I have the following code:

```
var uploadFile = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("..."));
driver.FileDetector = new LocalFileDetector();
uploadFile.SendKeys(myLocalPath);
```

This code works in all other browser-platform combinations except IE11 and Safari.

If I capture a screenshot immediately after the above code, it shows that the `<input type="file">` element is empty, whereas other browsers show the value of the `myLocalPath` variable.

I know that it does find the upload element; my suspicion is that the `SendKeys` method is either not working correctly on IE11/Safari and/or some security measure is preventing the text (`myLocalPath`) from being inserted.

Has anyone else come across this problem and found a solution?

Comment: Sounds like it could be similar to this (unresolved) bug report:

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3858

Comment: If you included a URL, it's not showing up in the published version of your comment.

Comment: Weird... try again! https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3858